# Hls videos (.m3u8 format) videos are not playing when they are placed in assets storage in offline mode in flutter,

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, flutter-layout, http-live-streaming, flutter-dependencies

**Hls videos (.m3u8 format) videos are not playing when they are placed in assets storage in offline mode in flutter,whereas .mp4 files works fine,how can i download hls videos and play offline by storing on local file storage?**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video Player'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          //m3u8 link

          ChewieDemo(
            looping: true,
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
                'videos/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8'
               
                ),
          ),
          //mp4link

          ChewieDemo(
            looping: true,
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(
              'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-forest-stream-in-the-sunlight-529-large.mp4',
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

.m3u8 file only contains text

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="English stereo",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_audio_1_stereo_128000.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=628000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=320x180,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_180_250000.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=928000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=480x270,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_270_400000.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1728000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_360_800000.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2528000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=960x540,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_540_1200000.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4928000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_720_2400000.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=9728000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="audio"
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_1080_4800000.m3u8
```

Comment: Hi, @Pravin have you found a solution for this? Am facing the same problem

Comment: No Jai not now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up on how HLS streaming works.
https://dougsillars.com/2017/10/26/how-hls-adaptive-bitrate-works/

The m3u8 files link to the .ts files that have the video - you'd need to download all the ts files.

To get the list of ts files for 720p video - look at this file:

```
f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_720_2400000.m3u8
```

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded all the ts files and copied them to the asset folder. On the android device, it's playing fine. But on the iOS device, it's not playing.

Comment: @JaiTechie can you share, how you have achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

HLS content can only be played when being served by a webserver, unless you use AVAssetDownloadURLSession to convert the .m3u8 to a .movpkg.